# Exception - Custom class initWithCoder unrecognized selector sent to instance in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I have an entity class which inherits NSObject that holds some data, and class name is "MessageDetails". i.e

MessageDetails.h Class-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MessageDetails : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *message;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dateString;

@end
```

MessageDetails.m Class-

```
#import "MessageDetails.h"

@implementation MessageDetails
@synthesize userImage, userName, message, dateString;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.userImage = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"userImage"];
        self.userName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"userName"];
        self.message = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"message"];
        self.dateString = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dateString"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:userImage forKey:@"userImage"];
    [coder encodeObject:userName forKey:@"userName"];
    [coder encodeObject:message forKey:@"message"];
    [coder encodeObject:dateString forKey:@"dateString"];
}

@end
```

In my View Controller class, I am sending some messages to Recipent .After sending successfully message, i am storing some values to "MessageDetails" class objects like userImage, userName, message and dateString, that i have to show in another class table view. So i am setting messageDetails object value successfully using NSUserDefault using this code..

```
     NSMutableArray *finalArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     array= [Util getArrayPreference:@"MessageDetails"];
     if (array) {
             [finalArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
           }

     [finalArray addObject:messageDetails];
     [Util setArrayPreference:finalArray forKey:@"MessageDetails"];
```

//For setting preferences

```
+(void)setPreference:(MessageDetails *)product forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:product];
    [prefs setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:key];
    [prefs synchronize];
}

+(void)setArrayPreference:(NSMutableArray *)products forKey:(NSString *)string
{
    for (int i=0; i<products.count; i++) {
        MessageDetails *po=[products objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *st=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        [Util setPreference:po forKey:st];

    }
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:products];
    [prefs setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:string];
    [prefs synchronize];
}
```

//For getting preferences

```
+(MessageDetails *)getPreference:(NSString *)key
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject1 = [defaults objectForKey:key];
    MessageDetails *obj = (MessageDetails *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myEncodedObject1];
    return obj;
}

+(NSMutableArray *)getArrayPreference:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject1 = [defaults objectForKey:string];
    NSMutableArray *arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *arr=(NSMutableArray *) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myEncodedObject1];
    for (int i=0;i<arr.count;i++) {
        NSString *st=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        [arr1 addObject:[Util getPreference:st]];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

But my problem is when i am calling getArrayPreference method then after

NSMutableArray *arr=(NSMutableArray *) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myEncodedObject1];

this line it is crashing. And an Exception that i am getting is

2013-08-25 12:32:22.802 SmsIndia[551:1d003] -[MessageDetails initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xae68160****

2013-08-25 12:32:22.802 SmsIndia[551:1d003] ***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MessageDetails initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xae68160'**

I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure what. Any help would be greatly appreciated ..., thank you!
If someone have any doubt related to question then let me know.

Comment: I have made correction in above code... Now it will work 100%  thanks 2 all

Comment: Hi Anand, what was the correction that was made? I seem to get getting this same error.

Comment: @TazHeyy dude..Use the same above code, it works. If you are getting same error again then try to change Entity class name and their key.

Comment: that's exactly what I did and it worked. Just wish I had seen your response earlier. It would have saved me a while debugging.

Comment: So where is the answer to this question or the correction that has been made to the code?

Comment: @jorisMansUse the same above code, it will give u the correct answer.

Comment: It would help to add some clarity on how this problem was fixed if this was fixed. The edit history also shows no info on what was fixed.